# What is the purpose of using Application variables?

Tags: asp-classic

I have been given responsibility over an asp classic site, and I ran across the following line of code. What is the purpose of this line of code and what does this syntax indicate?

```
Application("dbconn_ConnectionTimeout") = 90;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [application object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525360%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a variable that is stored on the server and is accessible by all instances of your application. In your scenario it appears that it is being used to store the period of time a database call can take before it times out.

```
// Database connections can take 90 seconds before they timeout
Application(“dbconn_ConnectionTimeout”) = 90;
```